# core-plot map data to x-axis

Tags: iphone, date, core-plot

I am not quite sure if core-plot is able to do this. I have a list of unix timestamps and some values and I need to display it as follows (Line graph)

- Each year has its own line
- X-Axis should show the month from Jan - Dec

En entry with the date 19.02.2011 should be between Feb and March in the x-axis.

Could someone give me a hint on how to do that?

**UPDATE**

I have an example from Excel how it should look like

[image]

Thanks a lot
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Plot includes several example apps that show how to plot dates along an axis. You can use a `CPTTimeFormatter` (a wrapper for an `NSDateFormatter`) to format the values. You have to pick a reference date and then compute the offset between each date value and the reference date. The plot datasource then provides these offsets as the plot data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not quite sure if that is doable. I looked at the different examples and didn't find a solution to that. I have edited my question and added a chart from excel.

Comment: You can definitely make a graph like that with Core Plot. The key is how you convert the timestamps to numbers. If they're already stored as doubles, you're all set. If they're stored as strings, you have to convert them to numbers first.